# How to coalesce multiple columns in a list of several dataframes based on part of the variable names?

Tags: r, dplyr, coalesce, mutate

I have a long list of data frames where in each dataframe, there are some columns that need to be coalesced based on the name. That is, the values in the columns including `Duo:` should replace the values in a corresponding row in a column whose name equals the string following `Duo:`. For instance, the non-NA values in `Duo:side` should replace the corresponding values in `side` column. Please see the data and the desired output below:

```
data <- list(foo = structure(list(id = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "NN"), bodyPart = c("leg", "arm", "knee", "eye"), side = c("LEFT", "RIGHT", "LEFT", "LEFT"), device = c("LLI", "LSM", "GHT", "LLM"), length = c(12, 476, 
  7, 2), mwID = c("a12", "k87", "j98", NA), `Duo:length` = c(23, NA, 77, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame"), bar = structure(list(id = c("DC", "DD", "FF", "ZZ"), bodyPart = c("ARM", "ear", "knee", "ankel"), side = c("RIGHT", "RIGHT", "RIGHT", 
  "LEFT"), device = c("RWS", "LSM", "YYY", "GOM"), tqID = c("fg12", "ll23", "sc26", "kj8"), `Duo:side` = c(NA, "LEFT", "LEFT", NA), `Duo:device` = c(NA, NA, NA, "GGT")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame"))

output <- list(foo = structure(list(id = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "NN"), bodyPart = c("leg", "arm", "knee", "eye"), side = c("LEFT", "RIGHT", "LEFT", "LEFT"), device = c("LLI", "LSM", "GHT", "LLM"), length = c(23, 476, 
  77, 2), mwID = c("a12", "k87", "j98", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame"), bar = structure(list(id = c("DC", "DD", "FF", "ZZ"), bodyPart = c("ARM", "ear", "knee", "ankel"), side = c("RIGHT", "LEFT", "LEFT", 
  "LEFT"), device = c("RWS", "LSM", "YYY", "GGT"), tqID = c("fg12", "ll23", "sc26", "kj8")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame"))
```

What I have done is the following which only works for one data frame and there is still a problem; I want the column that was coalesced to be removed. I know how to remove it separately but it would be great to do it in one go. I would appreciate your advice.

```
dplyr::mutate(data$foo, length = dplyr::coalesce(`Duo:length`, length))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way in base R. I would also recommend checking the function `dplyr::rows_update` which might come in handy in this case:

```r
out <- lapply(data, \(x){
  duo = grep("Duo", colnames(x), value = TRUE)
  og = gsub("Duo\\:\\.", "", duo)
  
  x[og] <- mapply(\(y, z) ifelse(complete.cases(z), z, y), x[og], x[duo])
  x[-grep("Duo", colnames(x))]
})

# $foo
#   id bodyPart  side device length mwID
# 1 AA      leg  LEFT    LLI     23  a12
# 2 BB      arm RIGHT    LSM    476  k87
# 3 CC     knee  LEFT    GHT     77  j98
# 4 NN      eye  LEFT    LLM      2 <NA>
# 
# $bar
#   id bodyPart  side device tqID
# 1 DC      ARM RIGHT    RWS fg12
# 2 DD      ear  LEFT    LSM ll23
# 3 FF     knee  LEFT    YYY sc26
# 4 ZZ    ankel  LEFT    GGT  kj8
```

Comment: Many thanks to the neat solution! It works perfectly on this sample data but I get an error `Error in `[.data.frame`(x, og) : undefined columns selected` because I did not mention that in my real data there is a dot following `Duo:`. That is, It is `Duo:.side`. Could you please advise me how to change this part `og = gsub("Duo\\:", "", duo)` so that it fits my data:

Comment: Yes, you can just add "\\." in the `gsub` call. see edit